# Lock over multiple methods

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have a singleton class (MySingletonClass) that has three main methods

1. BeginTransaction(clientId)
2. AddItem(item, clientId)
3. CommitTransaction(clientId)

The ClientClass is:

```
public class ClientClass
{

    private string id;

    private MySingletonClass s = MySingletonClass.Instance;

    public ClientClass()
    {
      id = new Guid().ToString();
    }
    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
       //start a lock here
       s.BeginTransaction(id);
    }
    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
       s.CommitTransaction(id);
       //end lock here
    }
    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
       //no access until lock is released
       s.AddItem(item, id);
    }
}
```

There are many task each of which with its own ClientClass class

I need a way to serialize access to singleton class by transaction:
if a transaction has not been committed then no other thread should start a new transaction or calla any other method on the singleton instance

For example every task can have code like this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
   Client c = new ClientClass();
   c.BeginTransaction();
   c.AddItem("www");
   c.AddItem("qqq");
   c.CommitTransaction();
});

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
   Client c1 = new ClientClass();
   c1.BeginTransaction();
   c1.AddItem("aaa");
   c1.CommitTransaction();
});
```

Any idea how can i archieve this with some sort of locking that starts on begin transaction and is released on commit?
All the examples i've seen of monitor , mutex and lock start and are released in the same method.
Is there a lock over multiple methods??

Comment: A mutex can be system wide. It's one of the ways that [you can accomplish a single-instance C# application](https://saebamini.com/Allowing-only-one-instance-of-a-C-app-to-run/).

Comment: That would be a really bad threading architecture, you will end up with all threads waiting for each other - meaning no real use of threads. Why not let each ClientClass have its own list, and when the Commit is called they `lock(s)` and populate their entire list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MySingletonClass` could look something like this:

```
public class MySingletonClass {
    private readonly Object _lockObject = new object();

    private List<string> _list = new List<string>();

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_lockObject);
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        if( Monitor.IsEntered(_lockObject) == false ) throw new ThreadStateException("Not owner of transaction");
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        if( Monitor.IsEntered(_lockObject) == false ) throw new ThreadStateException("Not owner of transaction");
        Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        if( Monitor.IsEntered(_lockObject) == false ) throw new ThreadStateException("Not owner of transaction");
        Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
    }
}
```

But if a ClientClass fails (exception being thrown) between `BeginTransaction` and `CommitTransaction`, it very important to call `RollbackTransaction` else all threads will deadlock since the monitor is never freed.

**So it is not a recommendable solution.**

Comment: Thanks Frank, i've already explored this solution but because of no such code was found   on google or microsoft documentation i was not sure if this solution was "recommendable". You are right when say that tha client class can hava an internal list and then commit as atomic operation on MySingletonClass, but for scenario where there are two phase commit the problem of having a multimethod lock persist.  can u therefore explain better why you think this could not be a "recommendable solution"? thanks in advance;)

Comment: If i see a solution like this, my architecture red alert would start immediately. The correct solution would be to look and refactor the overall architecture. I think you have ended in a http://xyproblem.info/.